# Banker's rounding with Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, math, c99

What's the easiest way to get ["Banker's rounding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) of floats with Visual C++ ? On other platforms/compilers I just use [rint](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rint), for which the default rounding mode is correct, but of course Visual Studio still does not support C99 `<math.h>` functions as of Visual Studio 2010.

---

*Note: Banker's rounding is the default rounding mode for IEEE-754 and is not the same as the more popular "round to nearest" - it's also known as round half to even, unbiased rounding, convergent rounding, statistician's rounding, Dutch rounding, Gaussian rounding, odd-even rounding, or broken rounding.*

Comment: Banker's rounding? Is that "always round to my advantage"? :)

Comment: `rint` is also included in C++11 (still not supported in Visual Studio 2012 though)